# How to register WCF service on windows server 2012 with IIS 8.0

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, windows-server-2012

I am new in asp.net, I have to access .svc from my application for that I have to deploy .svc service. But got this error when accessed my WCF service from browser,

HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found

The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.

Few suggested the solution to re-register asp.net.

I cannot register asp.net 4.0 or any other component from commad line on the windows server 2012 as it is giving me error message and commands me to do any installation from "windows add & remove features". I did so. But no luck.

I then tried to activate my webservice using  but then also no luck

```
<serviceActivations>
<add relativeAddress="integrate.svc" service="wcf.integrate" />
</serviceActivations>
```

I think there's a issue with windows server 2012 or IIS 8.0.
Please guide me where am I wrong.

Comment: in what folder your service is?

Comment: It was in some folder in C drive and after deployment it was within inetpub->wwwroot->folder. This problem is solved by the way, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

its almost the Same as you do in normal Windows.
1) first Publish your Service and then copy the Published folder inside wwwroot.
2) open IIS manager by typing inetmgr
3) now drill down to your Service in IIS Manager
       Sites -> "your service"
4). Right click on your Service Folder and select "Convert to Application". now your folder icon will be changed to Web icon.
5). now go to Content view of your service Application and browse your ".svc" or service file. you will see your service will be visible in the browser

**after adding your service to IIS. pls cross Verify two things**
1). extension .svc is available in your MIME types
2). "system.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler" is available in HTTP Handler
** if not please follow the below url to handle the same :- https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/publishing-a-wcf-service-on-iis8/

** also refer below URl to make sure HTTP Activation feature is enabled in your windows server
https://pubs.vmware.com/mirage-56/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.mirage.api.pg.doc%2FGUID-552D845B-E530-4898-A06B-4F73E668BEFF.html